# Delete a paragraph from a file using sed

Tags: sed

I have a markdown file that looks something like this:

markdown.md

```
# Title1

line 1
line 2
line 3

# Title2

line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I'd like to be able to delete one of the paragraphs by searching for the title. I would need to delete the title, the following line, and then every subsequent line that is not blank.

The desired output would be:

```
# Title2

line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I was doing some reading about using {} to group multiple commands together but I can't seem to quite get the syntax right.

```
cat markdown.md | sed '/^# Title1.*/,+1d {/^\s*$/d}'
```

My thinking was this would delete the line beginning with '# Title1', then the following line with ,+1d, then subsequent lines until a blank line, but i see the following error:

```
sed: 1: "/^# Title1.*/,+1d { ...": extra characters at the end of d command
```

I've tried a few variations but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it always just two paragraphs?

Comment: no, it could be any number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of sed puzzle that makes me wish for a slightly different tool.

```
sed -n -e '/Title1/!{p;d;};n;' -e ':a' -e 'n;/./ba'
```

Loosely translated: "Don't print anything. If it doesn't contain 'Title1', then all right, print it, then start over with the next line. But if it *does* contain 'Title1', then grab the next line (which will be blank), enter a loop, and keep grabbing new lines until you come to the next empty line."

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -z 's/# Title1[^#]*//' input_file
# Title2

line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^# /h;G;/\n# Title1/!P;d' file
```

If a line begins `#` , make a copy.

Append the copy to each line and if that line does not contain `\n# Title1`, print it.

Delete all lines.

---

Alternative:

```
sed '/^# Title1/{:a;N;/\n#/!s/\n//;ta;D}' file
```

Comment: I like the first one. The second... my version of sed does not handle loops as nimbly as yours.